# Regression - PCA - What to do with variables?

Tags: r, pca, feature-selection, leave-one-out

I am trying on a regression model with 44 variables.
Executing PCA due to multicollinearity, I receive 6 principal components.
I am using Leave-one-out cross-validation.

Unfortuneately, due to PCA and its "Measure of sample adequacy", which should be >0.5 for all variables in PCA, I have to exclude some variables.

Is this the variable/feature selection part of PCA?
Is it correct to say, that those variables aren't required to make a good prediction from these variables?

Thanks.

Comment: Why only 6 PCs from 44 variables?

Comment: I excluded 13 variables due to a MSA of below 0.5. With the rest of the variables, I get 6 PCs due to the KAISER-criterion (eigenvalue higher than 1). On the basis of the Velicer MAP, I would need to take 6 PCs.